# Why main() does not need a return type(say int), even when it return an intiger?

Tags: c, return, return-type

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
 //
 //
return 0;
}
```

I meant, the above code does not shows any error even though I didn't specify the return type of it. (simply 'main' instead of 'int main').

Comment: @jerry: I don't think it's a duplicate. This question isn't about the return type (`main()`, prior to C99, specifies a return type of `int`). This question is about the "implicit `int`" rule.

Comment: @jerry: I just voted to close this as a duplicate of that question -- though in a sense it's the opposite (this asks why there's no warning; the other asks why there is a warning). Still, the answer is essentially the same for both.

Answer (score 4):

This is old-style syntax (pre-C89) where the default return type of a function was `int`.

AFAIK it has been deprecated by now, so you should always provide a return type.

Comment: The implicit `int` rule was retained by the 1989 ANSI C standard (and by the equivalent 1990 ISO C standard). It was dropped by the 1999 ISO C standard. (It's never been a particularly good idea to depend on it.)

Answer (score 2):

#### 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. **It shall be defined with a return type of `int`** and with no
>   parameters:
>
> ```
>  int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Compiling it without return type, compiler should throw a warning:

```
[Warning] return type defaults to 'int' [enabled by default]
```

Answer (score 1):

As of the 1989/1990 C standard, a function with no return type specified implicitly returns `int`.

As of the 1999 C standard, the "implicit `int`" rule has been dropped, and an explicit return type is mandatory. (Compilers might not reject a program that violates this rule; often they merely issue a warning; you should still correct it.)

Even if you're using a pre-C99 compiler, you should still specify the return type.

The `main` function is correctly defined as:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

or as

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

or equivalent (or in some other implementation-defined manner, but there's rarely a good reason to use anything other than those two forms).

(Yes, you should use `(void)` rather than `()`. And yes, the return type of `main` is `int`, not `void`, though some permit it for some reason.)

Answer (score -2):

Due to downward compatibility, we use `int main()` in the programs. I think there is no many difference between `int main()` and `main()`. `main()` is useful in some older compilers. Now-a-days, We should use return type before `main()` function.

Comment: That's pretty much completely incorrect. `main()` is the old form; `int main()` was always legal, and `int main(void)` is the preferred form as of the 1989 standard. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21734031/827263) for details.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I answered it mistakenly.

Comment: You can delete your answer if you like.